# UIView Animation Fails

Tags: ios, uilabel, uiviewanimation

So, I want to do some basic animations of labels and later views.

I have a label, I'm trying to get it to move when a view loads, so I call the following method at the end of viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)animateView {
    NSLog(@"animateView");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:20 animations:^{
        // set new position of label which it will animate to
        self.dcFirstRunDaysLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20,320,280,215);
    }];
}
```

Instead of animating, the label appears in position.

I've tried every tutorial and read through the docs.  I get no errors.

Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling your animateView method in viewDidAppear. Because in viewDidLoad your view isn't visible yet.

viewDidLoad:
Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.

viewDidAppear:
Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

Comment: Just did that.  Is there a word for when a question appears on Stack Overflow moments after you try the fix yourself? There should be.  Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer.